# Does Laravel support return Redirect::back()->withFile()?

Tags: php, file, validation, laravel, form-submit

I'm new to Laravel,

if laravel have a validation on going with input text

`<input type="text name="title" />`

then when validation fails, it will return the input text value

`return Redirect::back()->withInput()`

does laravel have this function for file?

`<input type="file" name="testfile" />`

`return Redirect::back()->withFile()`

inorder to store the temp file in the `input type="file"` when validation fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not, and it could not.

When `Redirect::back()` is fired, a new HTTP request is being sent to the server. As HTTP is stateless, Laravel flashes the old input to the session handler and makes it available to you via the `Input::old()` function. Laravel then uses this information to pre-populate forms and text fields.

For security reasons however, you cannot pre-populate file fields, else a server could set any value it wanted to try and force you to upload any files from your computer!

Depending upon what you need, you would be able to store the file yourself and send the location of the file back using `Redirect::back()->with('file_location', '...')`. You won't be able to physically pre-populate the file input, but you could show something to the user when they're redirected back to let them know that they don't need to re-upload the file, unless they want to.